# How I can access to siblings of element in ionic 2?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I want to access siblings of the element when I clicked that, then hide siblings

```
<ion-list class="cat-list">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let cat of cats; let i=index" [ngClass]="{active: isGroupShown(i) , 'has-child': cat.nodes.length}" (click)="toggleGroup(i,cat.title)">
        <span>{{cat.title}}</span>
        <ul *ngIf="isGroupShown(i)">
            <li *ngFor="let subItem of cat['nodes'];"><span>{{subItem.title}}</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

my code of .ts file:

```
  shownGroup = null;

  .
  .
  .

  toggleGroup(group,title) {
    if (this.isGroupShown(group)) {
        this.shownGroup = null;
    } else {
        this.shownGroup = group;
        this.selectedCat = [title];
    };
  };
  isGroupShown(group) {
    return this.shownGroup === group;
  };
```

This is My output:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of your code? Did you triggered any errors? In order to help you, we'll need some more information.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby I have a accordion of categories, I want when one category was clicked, siblings of this will hide. same as ebay.com categories

Comment: Are you trying to create a custom one or using already existing component?

Comment: @Sampath I'm trying to create a custom

Comment: Are you creating an `Accordion` component? If yes can you show the image of it?

Comment: @Sampath I want when click on a category, siblings of that be hide

Comment: Hmm.. I know about below component.But unfortunately, it doesn't have siblings :( https://github.com/mahmoudissmail/ionic2Accordion

Comment: @Sampath two last items are siblings of the first item